# Simple Insert Statement works in MySQL Workbench but not PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have looked around and found some related articles but i can't seem to get to the bottom of what exactly I am doing wrong here.

I am trying to insert iterator, session username, latitude, longitude and address into coord table. I can't get the lat, long & address to work.

This is the mysql workbench code (works):

```
INSERT INTO coord(`iterator`,`username`,`lat`,`long`, `address`) VALUES(1,"Slacker1",37.76,-100.42,"213 Street San Diego CA");
```

This is the php (not working):

```
$con=mysqli_connect("server","sql_user","pw","db");
$lat=33.26;
$long=-100.33;
$uname=$_SESSION['username'];
$address="265 Road San Diego CA";

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO coord (`iterator`,`username`,`lat`,`long`,`address`) VALUES('$i','$uname','$lat','$long','$address')");
```

For reference here is the table code:

```
CREATE TABLE coord (
`iterator` int NULL,
`username` varchar(30) NULL,
`lat` Float(6,3) NULL,
`long` float(6,3) NULL,
`address` varchar(60) NULL
```

);

Thanks!

Working with the following: Appreciate the help! Staying up too late to work on these things making me forget simple things

```
$i=1;
$lat=33.26;
$long=-100.33;
$uname=$_SESSION['username'];
$address="265 Road San Diego CA";
mysqli_query($conW,"INSERT INTO coord (`iterator`,`username`,`lat`,`long`,`address`) VALUES('$i','$uname','$lat','$long','$address')");
```

Comment: You have a problem with the last name in your `Values()` clause.

Comment: Maybe the problem is: ,`$add make sure that if you already know the name of your database field, to just fill it in like: 'address'

Comment: Please do not actually use this code, it is very insecure as you are not escaping the inputs. Check out [mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: I am aware it is very insecure i am just trying to set it up, thank you for the note and i will look into it further as i develop security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a typo in the query.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO coord (`iterator`,`username`,`lat`,`long`,`address`) VALUES('$i','$uname','$lat','$long','$address')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the variables in your php query as part of the string. Remove the single quotes and append it to the string like this

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO coord (`iterator`,`username`,`lat`,`long`,`address`) VALUES('" . $i . "','" . $uname ."','" . $lat. "','" . $long . "','" . $address . "')");
```